# What is the max output length of a baseX encoding using "bitcoin style leading zero compressing"?

Tags: encoding, bitcoin

Given a baseX encoding using a ["bitcoin style leading zero compression"](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/base-x) and an input of `n` bytes, what is the maximum number of characters for the encoded string?
I know the answer for traditional base64 encodings, but I couldn't find an answer for this type of encoding, and I'm not entirely clear on the algorithm used.

For example, base64 encodes `n` bytes of input to an output string of length `4 * ⌈n / 3⌉` (or in code e.g.: `(n+2) / 3 * 4`). But what is the output length of the linked encoding algorithm? (I'm mainly interested in a sensible upper bound.)

Comment: I do not understand what to you mean with bitcoin style (too many interpretations). What it is the answer you know for *traditional* base64 encoding? (from your question, it seems infinite, but maybe you mean 64, but in this case it is clear from the code you linked the base of bitcoin). Just confused on what you are asking

Comment: 8 / log2(58) ~= 1.366 characters per byte. You need some extras for padding, and I do not know if there is a EndOfMessage character

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks, that's helpful! If you could provide a cursory explanation of the algorithm or a link to an internet resource for further studying, I'd gladly accept that as an answer